# Using OpenTLD lost object

Tags: c++, opencv, tracking

I am new over here so I will try to ask as accurate as I can.

I have using OpenTLD c++ version, but I have some problem with it, since it loses the object very easy. I have change some of the "Settings" trying to get it work better but without any success. I have also noticed that it has problems with interlaced videos.

My project is base on tracking a running person from behind, like this pic:

http://s14.postimg.org/5fac8v88x/Ejemplo5.png

I set the roi in the dorsal, it moves in every axis and has scale change a little bit faster than the OpenTLD can track.

I have looked everywhere for some information about tracking with fast scale changes but it seems to be not too much documentation.

The main changes of the code have been:

```
m_thetaP(0.95),
m_thetaN(0.35),
m_minSize(15),
m_camNo(0),
m_fps(30),
m_seed(0),
m_threshold(0.7),
m_proportionalShift(0.1),
```

Any idea of another code for tracking or where I should look for getting this more accurate?

Thanks!

PS:

I am also using HOG for the people detection when OpenTLD loses the tracking, but it works pretty bad too, I use the opencv sample code.